# Unreal Engine: How to render Stereo Panoramic Capture from single eye

Tags: unreal-engine4, panoramas

Unreal Engine has a plug in : Stereo Panoramic Capture. After enabling the plugin, the command:

**SP.PanoramicScreenshot**

renders two images, one from the left eye, and one from the right eye.

Is anyway we can only render from a single eye to save the render time?

I don't see any other command that allows me to do so, the only option seems to be hacking the source code.

[Stereo Panoramic Capture Reference](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Platforms/VR/StereoPanoramicCapture/Reference/index.html)

Comment: In this node write 1 instead 0 (default value)
[modified node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fq2Na.png)